# Expecting an arithmetic operator in SAS

Tags: sas

I get an error with this SAS code and I'm not sure what is wrong with it.

```
Data june;
infile "/home/u/Work/NHS/20200630-RTT-JUNE.csv" DLM=',';
'Gt 00 To 01 Weeks SUM 1'n = input('Gt 00 To 01 Weeks SUM 1'n);
run;
```

ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.

ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: I posted an full answer having tested it on communities.sas.com https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Error-when-using-infile-command/m-p/787352#M251571

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide the INPUT() function call with any informat specification to use.  The INPUT() function requires two arguments, the text string to convert and the informat to use to do the conversion.

Also your code will not do anything since you are not reading any data from the file you pointed to with the INFILE statement.

You probably need to use the INPUT statement instead.  For example code like this:

```
data june;
  infile "/home/u59602916/Work/NHS/20200630-RTT-JUNE-2020-full-extract-revised.csv" DLM=',';
  input 'Gt 00 To 01 Weeks SUM 1'n;
run;
```

Will attempt to one number from each line of the source text file.  It will read the characters up to the first comma on the line.

If you really have a CSV file you should use the DSD option and not just the DLM= option.  That will properly handle values that might be enclosed in quotes because they contain the delimiter.  It will also properly treat adjacent delimiters as indicating an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

Use the put *function* if you want to convert numeric values to character. Also, you'll need to use the input *statement* to indicate the variable(s) you would like to read in from the external file.

```
Data june;
    infile "/home/u59602916/Work/NHS/20200630-RTT-JUNE-2020-full-extract-revised.csv" DLM=',';
    input 'Gt 00 To 01 Weeks SUM 1'n $;
    'Gt 00 To 01 Weeks SUM 1'n = put('Gt 00 To 01 Weeks SUM 1'n, 4.);
run;
```

If you want to read in a numeric value, don't use a function, simply use the input statement as above (without the dollar sign to indicate numeric).

```
Data june;
    infile "/home/u59602916/Work/NHS/20200630-RTT-JUNE-2020-full-extract-revised.csv" DLM=',';
    input 'Gt 00 To 01 Weeks SUM 1'n ;
run;
```

http://support.sas.com/kb/24/590.html

https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.2/lestmtsref/n1rill4udj0tfun1fvce3j401plo.htm#p1sic7f8w8x1wpn1i07zx5vhwdwj